# CoreText memory leak from CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString

Tags: memory-leaks, core-text

I'm coming across a problematic leak which - thanks to Instruments - appears to be coming from CTFrameSetterCreateWithAttributedString. The call stack is below.

```
1 CoreText -[_CTNativeGlyphStorage prepareWithCapacity:preallocated:]
2 CoreText -[_CTNativeGlyphStorage initWithCount:]
3 CoreText +[_CTNativeGlyphStorage newWithCount:]
4 CoreText TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*)
5 CoreText TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*)
6 CoreText TFramesetterAttrString::TFramesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*)
7 CoreText CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString
```

The code generating this call stack is:

```
CFAttributedStringRef attrRef = (CFAttributedStringRef)self.attributedString;
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrRef);
CFRelease(attrRef);
...
CFRelease(framesetter);
```

self.attributedString gets released elsewhere. I feel like I'm correctly releasing everything else... Given all this, where could the leak be coming from? It's fairly significant for my purposes - 6-10 MB a pop. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Still can't figure this one out, and suspect it might be an Apple bug. Have filed a report - will update here if any response.

Comment: You said `self.attributedString gets released elsewhere`, while you release `attrRef` in the code snippet above. Maybe it is your releasing that object twice that causes some other problems, which affects other code, and CFRelease is not called at all, just guessing...

Comment: Interesting idea - thanks. But I think that ```CFRelease()``` just releases Core Foundation objects, and any Cocoa objects (like NSAttributedString) must be released separately.

Comment: If you are under ARC, you rarely need to deal with deallocation of Cocoa objects(unless you transfer ownership of Cocoa objects to Core Foundation objects), `(CFAttributedStringRef)self.attributedString` is like `(__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)self.attributedString`, which **does not** transfer ownership of `self.attributedString` to `CFAttributedStringRef`, so you shouldn't have called `CFRelease` on `attrRef `. If you want to manage memory deallocation of the object in the Core Foundation side, `__bridge__transfer` or `CFRetain` is what you need, but I don't think you should.

Comment: I'm not under ARC, but I see your point. In any case, I tried removing the additional ```CFRelease``` on ```attRef``` but it doesn't deal with the problem (unfortunately!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491841/memory-usage-grows-with-ctfontcreatewithname-and-ctframesetterref/17248890#17248890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem was substantially addressed by not using an ivar for a CFMutableArrayRef. We were using the Akosma Obj-C wrapper for CoreText, and in the AKOMultiColumnTextView class there's a CFMutableArrayRef _frames ivar which - for some reason - is hanging around even after CFRelease calls. Not having the _frames ivar is a bit expensive, but has drastically improved memory usage. Thanks Neevek for your contributions.