# Potential leaks in code converted to ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have translated some code of a library to ARC and i suspect I have failed to do so properly. Basically i have added som `__bridge` commands to the code. Xcode complains during analyze, saying that there is a potential leak of an object stored in `path`. The code is attached below. Can you help me fix the potential leak issue of the next to last line:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(self.text.length<=0) {
        self.text = EMPTY;
        return;
    }

    //Prepare View for drawing
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context,CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,0,([self bounds]).size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context,1.0,-1.0);

    //Get the view frame size
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;

    //Determine default text color
    UIColor* textColor = nil;
    if(!self.highlightColor||!(textColor=[self.highlightColor objectForKey:kRegexHighlightViewTypeText])) {
        if([self.textColor isEqual:[UIColor clearColor]]) {
            if(!(textColor=[[RegexHighlightView highlightTheme:kRegexHighlightViewThemeDefault] objectForKey:kRegexHighlightViewTypeText]))
               textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        } else textColor = self.textColor;
    }

    //Set line height, font, color and break mode
    CGFloat minimumLineHeight = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font].height,maximumLineHeight = minimumLineHeight;
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)self.font.fontName,self.font.pointSize,NULL);
    CTLineBreakMode lineBreakMode = kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    //Apply paragraph settings
    CTParagraphStyleRef style = CTParagraphStyleCreate((CTParagraphStyleSetting[3]){
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight,sizeof(minimumLineHeight),&minimumLineHeight},
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight,sizeof(maximumLineHeight),&maximumLineHeight},
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode,sizeof(CTLineBreakMode),&lineBreakMode}
    },3);
    NSDictionary* attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)font,(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName,(__bridge id)textColor.CGColor,(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,(__bridge id)style,(NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil];

    //Create path to work with a frame with applied margins
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path,NULL,CGRectMake(MARGIN+0.0,(-self.contentOffset.y+0),(size.width-2*MARGIN),(size.height+self.contentOffset.y-MARGIN)));


    //Create attributed string, with applied syntax highlighting
    CFAttributedStringRef attributedString = (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)[self highlightText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:attributes]];

    //Draw the frame
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString);
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,CFAttributedStringGetLength(attributedString)),path,NULL);
    CTFrameDraw(frame,context);
}
```

[image: Here is a preview from the profiling after releasing path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HaIR's definition is a little incomplete: The compiler only manages Objective-C types.  Anything that follows the `create` rule, or is `malloc`'d, `calloc`'d or `new`'d onto the heap is your responsibility.  The memory leaks you've got stem from 4 distinct instances of not balancing a function with `create` in it's name with the properly prefixed `...release()` call.

You can fix number 1 with a call to `CGPathRelease()`, number 2 with a call to `-autorelease` for that attributed string (assuming ARC is off, which given the circumstances, it is if Instruments is complaining), numbers 3 and 4 can be fixed with two calls to `CFRelease()`.

Comment: what do you mean arc is of? this is an ARC activated project

Comment: Yes, but if the setter is complaining, then either you're indirectly retaining the returned object (resulting in a +2 reference count), or that call to create a frame setter is retaining the string (unlikely).  It should go away when you release the frame setter properly if ARC is enabled.

Comment: also i cant find the function CTRelease, do i need some extra import for this? Thank you

Comment: My bad, typo. It should say CFRelease()

Answer (score 0):

In [the manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), it mentions that the compiler doesn't automatically manage CF objects.  You must call `CFRetain` and `CFRelease`, according to CF memory management rules.

so you need a `CGPathRelease(path)`; at some point.

Comment: do i also need to handle: __bridge CFAttributedStringRef) differently?

Comment: I'm 98% sure that its ok ;) So I looked for a few specific Questions about it, like this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10285149/793607

Comment: I think you need to cast the CFAttributedString stuff on the other two lines with __block.  But I'm feeling blasted...